# SQL. Прмогите с написанием запроса

Tags: sql

Предположим, вы открыли интернет-магазин и теперь хотите узнать, сколько времени проходит между каждым последующим продажами. У вас есть одна таблица журнала, в которой вы храните метку времени каждой совершенной вами продажи.

1. Напишите запрос SQL, который покажет разницу во времени для каждой последующей продажи.
2. Напишите запрос SQL, который покажет максимальную разницу во времени между двумя последовательными продажами.

Я написала так: но вот если я укажу MAX(DATEDIFF(second, timestamp, next_time)), то мне кажется так не заработает:

```
SELECT  timestamp,
LEAD(timestamp) OVER(ORDER BY timestamp) next_time, 
DATEDIFF(second, timestamp, next_time),   
FROM log
```

Comment: @Akina подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы не можете использовать алиас выражения выходного набора в другом выражении выходного набора. Используйте само выражение вместо алиаса.

Comment: Нажмите ссылку "закрыть" под текстом вопроса. Прочитайте пункт "Необходимо конкретизировать" и его описание. И срочно исправьте вопрос, пока его не закрыли.

Comment: @Akina у меня нет меню закрыть

Comment: В общем - нельзя задавать несколько вопросов в одной теме...

Comment: так это другая тема

Comment: Угу... в которой ДВА вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с оконными функциями желательно использовать СТЕ. В данном случае оно излишне, конечно, но лучше привыкайте пока всегда делать так.

```
WITh cte AS ( SELECT [timestamp],
              LEAD([timestamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [timestamp]) next_time
              FROM log )
SELECT [timestamp],
       COALESCE(DATEDIFF(SECOND, [timestamp], next_time), 0) difference
FROM cte;
```

PS. Использовать зарезервированное слово в качестве имени поля - путь на поле с граблями.

PPS. Для вывода максимальной разницы нужно просто отсортировать по убыванию и взять первую запись.

Comment: А можно так написать? Будет ли так работать?
           SELECT [timestamp],
              LEAD([timestamp]) OVER (ORDER BY [timestamp]) next_time, 
              DATEDIFF(SECOND, [timestamp], next_time)
              FROM log

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova Посмотрите ещё раз на самый первый мой комментарий к вопросу...